# How do I compare the "state" of two objects of the same type?

Tags: java, inheritance, equals

I'm supposed to create my own equals() method which overrides the equals(method) of the parent class. This method accepts a Counter object as its argument. In the code below, I want an easy way to determine if the Counter object argument equals the *current* instance of the Counter class, if that makes sense. I have achieved this in the code below by comparing the fields of each object one by one, but I want a simpler way to do it. Something that looks like this would be nice: "result = (otherCounter == new Counter(min,max) ? true : false);", but I know that's not right and it gets an error. How do I compare the equality of the variables in the two Counter objects, so that c1.equals(c2) will be false if Counter objects c1 and c2 are different?

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{

    boolean result = true;
    if (otherObject instanceof Counter)
    {

        Counter otherCounter = (Counter)otherObject;

            result = (otherCounter.min == this.min) &&  
                    (otherCounter.max == this.max) &&
                    (otherCounter.currentCount == this.currentCount) &&
                    (otherCounter.rolloverOccurrence == this.rolloverOccurrence) ? true : false;

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should initialise `result` to `false`, because if it's not the instance of object, then it's not equal.  I would say you're current implementation is just fine, sure, it's long winded, by  that's the best result you're going to get

Comment: Not part of the question but don't forget the override hashCode when you override equals...

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading is not possible in Java.
And to compare two object are equal or not you should use .equals() method no matter what.
Ex: obj1.equals(obj2)

It is because sometimes Java API (ex: Collections) will internally call equals method to sort the collection. So there is no simple way to compare but to use equals()

Answer (score 0):

Your method is just fine like this except for the other answers you got here that state that there is not overloading of operators in Java, the thing with the `result = true` instead of `false` and commenting you remember to override `hashCode` if you didn't already do. Let me give you one more advise. The method can be written in some more compact way:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (!(obj instanceof Counter)) {
       return false;
   }
   Counter other = (Counter) obj;
   return other.min == this.min && other.max == this.max &&
       other.currentCount == this.currentCount &&
       other.rolloverOccurrence == this.rolloverOccurrence;
}
```